# Binary heat plot in Python

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, binary-matrix

I'm new to python and need help. I'm trying to produce a binary matrix (presence/absence) with the following data in a CSV format. I have tried several codes found in chats, but non of them solved the problem.

| site_Name | tool1 | tool2 | tool3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| site2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| site3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| site4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I have tried to convert the dataset into numpy array, transposed the dataset, dropping columns, etc

Comment: Don't paste text as an image. I've proposed an edit to format the table correctly. Please include what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: What you want as output? Graph or any specific output. Also share the link of your CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a seaborn heatmap:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N, M = 10, 20
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(N, M) * 2).astype(int),
                  columns=[f'tool{i + 1:02d}' for i in range(M)],
                  index=[f'site{i + 1:02d}' for i in range(N)])
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, lw=1, cbar=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap of binary data]

Comment: Hi JohanC Tanks for your answer.  Actually, the data i try to plot is not random and every site  and tool has a name (a bit dufficult). It is why i have used site and tools.

Comment: Well, you store your information in a dataframe (possibly reading in a dataframe). And then use `sns.heatmap(...)` using that dataframe. If you'd redo the edit of @SaaruLindestøkke you could directly read your dataframe from the website.  Please note that data as image is not allowed at StackOverflow.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the column "site name" is the problem. When I drop it, I'm able to plot the data.  Here is the error "could not convert string to float: 'AnyamabaLayer _''

Comment: You need to set that column as index of your dataframe e.g. `df = df.set_index("site name")`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Johan !!!!! it worked.  Setting the index was the solution.